# How to configure Exchange (SBS 2003) for Outlook Anywhere

Tags: windows-server-2003, exchange-2003, outlook-anywhere

What needs to be done on the server to give Outlook access remotely?

Comment: A lot. Seriously, entire chapters in books have been written about this subject. Methinks you should read SBS 2003 Unleashed and do some Google searching because if it was written out here, it would probably reach the character limit for posting at ServerFault server times over. Then again, considering some of Evan Anderson's posts, I think the character limit for posts might be capable of handling a chapter or two... =)

Comment: Since you've already deployed consistent with the "How to Deploy RPC over HTTP for the First Time in Small Business Server 2003 (Standard or Premium)" TechNet article, can you provide some detail on the failure mode observed?

Answer (score 1):

As with all things in Small Business Server, it is best to make sure you go about this in an SBS-sanctioned way--I've gotten myself in trouble in SBS assuming that since I could get a feature working in the full product, I should be able to make it work on SBS no problem... SBS has many moving parts all installed on a single server which creates some unique interactions you may not see when deploying the same solution using multiple servers and the full licensed product!

Given that, I'd start with this Microsoft TechNet article which specifically addresses enabling RPC-over-HTTP on SBS 2003: [How to Deploy RPC over HTTP for the First Time in Small Business Server 2003 (Standard or Premium)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123622(EXCHG.65).aspx)

[One of the things you may need to do (if you've not done so already) is to deploy an SSL certificate. You can go with a self-signed certificate or one signed by a recognized Certificate Authority (CA)... going with a self-signed certificate is the inexpensive route, but depending on your deployment and user community, using a "real" CA-signed certificate can save you some headaches. Should you choose to go that route, I'd recommend using [DigiCert](http://www.digicert.com/016727/). They're not the cheapest, but are reasonably priced and their service and support is stellar; I wouldn't use anyone else.]

Good luck!

Comment: I did the self-signed certificate. Small office setup. I did read the Technet article that you suggested and did implement the changes mentioned.  but something is not right.

Comment: Good effort! and +1 for " it is best to make sure you go about this in an SBS-sanctioned way" I found that out the hard way. =(